# Setting theme for legacy controls

Tags: c++, winapi, themes, chromium-embedded

We have a Windows C++ application that uses legacy Windows API `CreatePopupMenu` and `TrackPopupMenuEx` to render context menus. However, after I updated some external library (namely CEF, *Chromium Embedded Framework*), all of our context menus now show in a dark theme (not only those of CEF). This is unwanted, because the rest of our application is always in a light theme disregarding user settings.

So, some change in the CEF library must be calling some Win32 API that changes the theme across our application. I already posted a [question on CEF's own support forum](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=19495&p=53818#p53818), but I have not been able to fix the issue yet. My new approach is to let CEF change the theme; I'll just change it back. The question is, *how do I do this*.

This question is not directly about CEF; it's about Win API and how to override the theme for all newly created windows.

Comment: Just a guess here - perhaps you can grab the popup menu's underlying `HWND` (using `FindWindowEx()` or `SetWindowsHookEx()` while displaying your menu), and then pass that `HWND` to [`SetWindowTheme()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) to remove the current theme from it.

Comment: I don't think I can do that, because TrackPopupMenuEx opens the menu and blocks until it closes. I can, however, use SetWindowTheme on the HWND that opens the menu. That removes the theme altogether, and the result is a menu that looks as in Windows 3.1, not the light theme I would normally get.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501268/win10-dark-theme-how-to-use-in-winapi and its answers; the dark mode APIs are still inexplicably undocumented, even though Microsoft have published code showing how to use them. Probably calling `SetPreferredAppMode` is what you want to turn off dark context menus.

Comment: @digorydoo FYI, you can still run code while `TrackPopupMenuEx()` blocks. For instance, by calling `SetWindowsHookEx()`  before `TrackPopupMenuEx()` to install a thread-local hook to catch the creation of the popup menu's window. Or using `SetTimer()` or `PostMessage()` to post messages to the popup menu's owner window while `TrackPopupMenuEx()` pumps the message queue.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the following hack to get the light mode back. It's really ugly, because it uses undocumented Windows API, which may break at any time.

```
void restoreLightMode()
{
   enum class PreferredAppMode { Default, AllowDark, ForceDark, ForceLight };
   using fnRtlGetNtVersionNumbers = void (WINAPI *)(LPDWORD major, LPDWORD minor, LPDWORD build);
   using fnAllowDarkModeForApp = bool (WINAPI *)(bool allow); // ordinal 135, in 1809
   using fnSetPreferredAppMode = PreferredAppMode(WINAPI *)(PreferredAppMode appMode); // ordinal 135, in 1903
   auto hNTDLL = GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll");

   if (hNTDLL)
   {
      auto RtlGetNtVersionNumbers = reinterpret_cast<fnRtlGetNtVersionNumbers>(GetProcAddress(hNTDLL, "RtlGetNtVersionNumbers"));

      if (RtlGetNtVersionNumbers)
      {
         DWORD major, minor, buildNumber;
         RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(&major, &minor, &buildNumber);
         buildNumber &= ~0xF0000000;

         if (major >= 10 && (
            buildNumber == 17763 || // 1809
            buildNumber == 18362 || // 1903
            buildNumber == 18363 || // 1909
            buildNumber == 19041 || // 2004
            buildNumber >= 19042 // over 2009
            ))
         {
            HMODULE hUxtheme = LoadLibraryExW(L"uxtheme.dll", nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);

            if (hUxtheme)
            {
               auto ord135 = GetProcAddress(hUxtheme, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(135));

               if (buildNumber < 18362)
               {
                  auto AllowDarkModeForApp = reinterpret_cast<fnAllowDarkModeForApp>(ord135);
                  AllowDarkModeForApp(false);
               }
               else
               {
                  auto SetPreferredAppMode = reinterpret_cast<fnSetPreferredAppMode>(ord135);
                  SetPreferredAppMode(PreferredAppMode::ForceLight);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Code was taken from https://github.com/komiyamma/win32-darkmode